# Como solucionar error al importar archivos js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estimados estaría agradecido de su ayuda, tengo un proyecto donde requiero la librería **dropdown.js** de **Bootstrap**, pero al incluir el script me da el siguiente error, mencionar que todos los archivos se encuentran en la raíz del proyecto.

**dropdown.js:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './jquery.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'**

Estas son las primeras líneas del archivo **dropdown.js**

```
import $ from './jquery.min.js'
import Popper from './popper.min.js'
import Util from './util'
```

Y esta es la estructura html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../summernote/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../summernote/summernote.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="summernote"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <button class="prueba btn btn-success" type="button">Agregar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="../summernote/dropdown.js"></script> 
<script src="../summernote/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../summernote/popper.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../summernote/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="../summernote/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 

<script src="../summernote/summernote.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.summernote').summernote({

        })

        $('.prueba').click(function(){
            let img = document.createElement('img');
            $(img).attr('src','https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
            $('.summernote').summernote('insertImage','https://images.pexels.com/photos/1591447/pexels-photo-1591447.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500','prueba')
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de JQuery estás usando? Las versiones antiguas no usan la sintaxis `export`.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 3.6.0

Comment: Por lo que estoy viendo, estas importando `dropdown.js` antes de `jquery.min.js` en tu html. Ahí está el error. Importa primero jquery ya que dropdown depende de ella. El orden en que los declaras en tu html importa.

Comment: cambie el orden de los archivos y aun así me sigue arrojando dicho error